# Get the size of a vector that is an element in a vector that is a pointer

Tags: c++, for-loop, pointers, vector, size

```cpp
for(int i=0; i < synthesizer_->GetNotation()->size(); i++){
   for(int j=0; j < synthesizer_->GetNotation()[i]->size(); j++){}
}
```

I want to display the elements of a vector of vectors, row by row.
The error (right after `[i]`) is:

```
base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'std::vector<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >'
```

`GetNotation()` returns a pointer to the vector of vectors.

I'm assuming the error is telling me the syntax is incorrect (but I'm not sure).

I don't know how else to access the contained vectors except by the index in a bracket. I've searched and can't find an explanation or code example.

```
protected: std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > notation_;
std::vector<std::vector<std::string> >* GetNotation(){return &notation_;}
```

Comment: What does `GetNotation()` return?

Comment: Show the return type of `GetNotation`. Don't try to describe it in words, just show the exact declaration of the function.

Comment: GetNotation() returns a pointer to a vector of vectors.

Answer (score 1):

If `GetNotation()` returns a `vector*` pointer (why not a `vector&` reference?), then you need to first dereference the pointer to access the `vector` being pointed at, before you then try to access the vector's `operator[]`, eg:

```cpp
for(size_t i = 0; i < synthesizer_->GetNotation()->size(); ++i){
   for(size_t j = 0; j < (*(synthesizer_->GetNotation()))[i].size(); ++j){
      // use (*(synthesizer_->GetNotation()))[i][j] as needed...
   }
}
```

Which would be much easier to manage and read if you call `GetNotation()` only one time and cache the result in a local variable, eg:

```cpp
auto notation = synthesizer_->GetNotation();
for(size_t i = 0; i < notation->size(); ++i){
   auto &strings = (*notation)[i];
   for(size_t j = 0; j < strings.size(); ++j){
     // use strings[j] as needed...
   }
}
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
auto &notation = *(synthesizer_->GetNotation());
for(size_t i = 0; i < notation.size(); ++i){
   auto &strings = notation[i];
   for(size_t j = 0; j < strings.size(); ++j){
     // use strings[j] as needed...
   }
}
```

That being said, you could use iterators instead of indexes:

```cpp
auto notation = synthesizer_->GetNotation();
for(auto i = notation->begin(); i != notation->end(); ++i){
   auto &strings = *i;
   for(auto j = strings.begin(); j != strings.end(); ++j){
     // use *j as needed...
   }
}
```

In which case, you could use [range-based `for` loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) instead, eg:

```cpp
for(auto &strings : *(synthesizer_->GetNotation())){
   for(auto &str : strings){
     // use str as needed...
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this.